# "each other" OR " one another"

Tags: meaning

Which one is correct? In case both of them are correct, which one is more common?

> - How long have you and John known **each other**?
> - How long have you and John known **one another**?

Comment: It's a free choice in your example. As compound reciprocal pronouns, "each other" and "one another" are semantically equivalent, the former being more common

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Traditionally, each other refers to two people and one another refers
>   to more than two people, but this distinction is disappearing in modern English.

So, to do things the proper way, you might want to use '`each other`'.

You should check out this [source](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/pronouns/reciprocal-pronouns-each-other-and-one-another).